# Alias for Ubuntu package 'gcc' not found but 'gcc-4.8' found

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

So I checked in the terminal

`gcc --version`

command not found

But when I check

`gcc-4.8 --version`

it outputs the proper information about this gcc.

The question is how can I type `gcc --version`

and it calls the proper executable file which is gcc-4.8. Is that related to alias or anything?

Comment: Please upgrade your Ubuntu distribution. The current gcc is 9 and GCC 4.8 is obsolete, see https://gcc.gnu.org/ and notice there is no reason to use an obsolete `gcc`

Comment: I tried to configure my deep learning setup for tensorflow with GPU support and in their config chart they use gcc 4.8 for CUDA 10, cuDNN 7.4 and tensorflow 1.14. I just tried to follow its safe config as version compatibility issue already takes so much time before.

Comment: GCC 9 is upward compatible with GCC 4.8

Answer (score -1):

I use the below command to kinda make it work, if there is any potential issue?

`ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.3 /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: Yes. Both GCC 4.8 and GCC 4.3 are obsolete, unmaintained, with potential bugs  and less features than the current [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/). Also `/usr/bin/gcc` is a symlink managed by Ubuntu. BTW your question is off-topic here (see https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ...)